# Magnific Popup with Select Box

Tags: magnific-popup

I am trying to use Magnific Popup with a select box. Initially I was attempting to form the options like this:

```
<option class="popup-modal" value="#<%= counties[i].Code %>">
```

The SelectBox has a onchange set to send "this.value" to a Javascript function:

```
var doPopUp = function(county){
    console.log(county);
    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        preloader: false,
        focus: '#username',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay: 300,
        modal: true
    });
};
```

This is not opening the popup however.

If I give the select element the following:

```
<select class="popup-modal" onchange="href=this.value">
```

This opens the popup but it just says "true".

I am very new to Magnifi and am feeling pretty lost at the moment.

Has anyone had luck in using Magnific Popup with Select Boxes?

Answer (score 0):

This solved it...

```
<select onchange="doPopUp(this.value)">
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">
-Select County-
</option>
<% for (var i = 0; i < counties.length; i++) { %>
    <option value="#<%= counties[i].Code %>">
    <%= counties[i].Name %>
    </option>
<% } %>
</select>
```

and then...

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
        type: 'inline',
        preloader: false,
        focus: '#username',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay: 300,
        modal: true,
        items:{
            src:county
        }
    });
```